# Mixing VPN Protocols

Tags: vpn, openvpn, obfuscation, wireguard

Is there any benefit to mixing vpn protocols as far as obfuscating your traffic. Would a multiple hop setup like (openvpn(server1) + wireguard(server2)) be better or is (openvpn(server1) + openvpn(server2)) just as good.

Comment: *Better* in what context? Encrypted traffic is not obfuscated. VPN-to-VPN connections are not common and will standout to anyone in a position to look.

Comment: @user10216038 thanks for answering. I'm confused though, wouldn't the first vpn, encapsulate the second vpn's traffic so your isp wouldn't see it?

Comment: It's not the ISP that would see the double VPN. Both VPNs would know they are connected to another VPN. So too would any network monitoring between the two VPNs. You have to ask yourself what you are trying to accomplish by chaining VPNs.

Comment: @user10216038: As I understand, this is a similar issue to trying to use TOR to obfuscate information? In that, as I understand regarding TOR, its traffic would be relatively unique looking from a network monitoring aspect, and they would just need to have access to the exit nodes to know what was being sent over the traffic?

Comment: @Alexander The 1st - In the case of Tor, yes but seeing exit node traffic has **no attribution** back to any specific originator. Yes Tor traffic is pretty easy to identify but difficult to trace.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Pick a VPN you trust, and stick with that.  If you don't trust it, why would you run it with another one that you do?  Just run the one you like.

Otherwise, you're going to be maintaining a rather complicated network for no added benefit.  Also, you're more likely to implement something wrong, and open vulnerabilities if you make the implementation too complex.

Forget about OpenVPN. I wrote an article explaining why: [Just use WireGuard](https://consensus.enterprises/blog/protecting-cloud-networks-wireguard-ansible/).

*To state my bias explicitly (as requested), I'm a founding partner in the firm whose blog it is.*

Comment: your article doesn't explain why to just use wireguard. Also https://lwn.net/Articles/850098/